# reading arduino serial output line by line using redpark cable?

Tags: ios, serial-port, arduino, ttl

I'm developing an IOS app that reads Arduino serial output via redpark cable.
In the Arduino side, it uses Serial.println() to send out strings.
The string is in the format of "12.34x334.45x0.34x123x33". Essentially it's a combination of doubles with "x" in between as a special split character.
My initial thought was that in the app side, it would get the Arduino output line by line so I would just use

```
NSString *testString= @"12.34x334.45x0.34x123x33";
NSArray *array = [testString componentsSeparatedByString:@"x"];
```

to get a NSArray contains 12.34  334.45 0.34 123 and 33.

Somehow after reading questions and answers posted here, I figured out there is no way for redpark sdk to treat the Arduino output line by line, it's always in a X bytes basis.

In order to parse the Arduino output string correctly, what should i do? Would it be a good idea to add leading and tailing 0 to my double data to make the original string to be sent in a fixed length?
(i.e. "03.45x45.50x02.30" to make it 17 bytes and try to read 17 bytes of data using redpark sdk?)

Comment: Not necessarily. For example, you could read the input character by character, store it in a buffer, and when you come across a line break, treat the contents of a buffer as a line.

Answer (score 0):

The Redpark SDK only grabs the incoming serial data stream, but doesn't (despite having a few helper routines) interpret it as packets. You'll need to code that yourself. As suggested by agentatlarge in the comments to your question, read the data into a buffer using `readBytesAvailable:numBytes` until you get a new line character (ASCII 13), at which point you have your string to parse and can start over.

Alternatively, skip the initial string: read the incoming data until you get an "x" (at which time you add a string to an `NSMutableArray`) *or* a new line character (at which point you process the array and start a new one.

Be aware that, using the default settings (configurable in `redparkSerial.h`) data will be fed to you in chunks limited to 100ms (`rxForwardingTimeout`) or 16 bytes (`rxForwardCount`), whichever comes sooner. So your system will need to be able to handle multiple reads until it is certain that it has received all the data in a packet (printed line), evidenced by the arrival of the new line character.